# OneToMany composite primary key on same entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, one-to-many

I want to do the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="things")
public class Thing
{
    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Thing> alreadyMatchedThings;

    //getters and setters
}
```

As expected, this creates table things_things, and because both columns will sometimes have the same value repeated, what I really want is to treat these two columns (the id and the foreign key) as a composite primary key.

Not too unexpectedly, I get the error Duplicate entry '1165f4a1-c369-41ea-888c-0e3798deb04f' for key 'alreadyMatchedThings_id'

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose I could simply go for:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="things")
public class Thing
{
    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="sourcethingid")
    private Set<MatchedThing> matchedThings;

    //getters and setters
}
```

where

```
@Entity
public class MatchedThings
{
    @Id
    private String id;

    private Thing matchedThing;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Well done, me.